# How can my webapp be resolving with invalid Host?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cloudflare, sentry

No sure how this could happen but I am getting 404 errors where the request data in my sentry project makes no sense. The project is using CloudFlare for DNS then it goes through an AWS network.

```
curl \
 -H "Accept: */*" \
 -H "Content-Length: " \
 -H "Content-Type: " \
 -H "Host: ${ip}" \
 -H "User-Agent: curl/7.64.1" \
 -H "X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=[Filtered]" \
 -H "X-Forwarded-For: [Filtered]" \
 -H "X-Forwarded-Port: 443" \
 -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" \
 "http://${ip}/"
```

How can my project throw a 404 when the requests hitting it are `http://${ip}/`. I don't see how this request could resolve to the project.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How can this be resolving?
3. Is this an issue with CloudFlare or AWS?

Comment: What is the `curl` command? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: I get the same errors, hosted on AWS / Fargate - probably a couple per day. Sometimes I will get a 15 or so at once randomly.